# How would that be possible to have more than one ShadowBox links on one page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, shadowbox

I'm using Shadowbox on my page: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html

I have 2 links on 2 separate web user controls on the same page which should open 2 different pages.

I'm using the below function to initialize my shadowbox:

```
function InitializeShadowbox() {           
            Shadowbox.init({
                onOpen: shadowboxOpen,
                onFinish: shadowboxFinish,
                onClose: shadowboxClose,
                modal: true
            });
            // this will cause the shadowbox to setup itself again after a partial porstback.
            Shadowbox.setup();
        }
```

But the problem is that Shadowbox.init() function is a static function on a static class so apparently it's not possible to have more than one shadowbox link with different initializers?

I wish I could just create a new instance of shadowbox, name it and work with it.

I'd need to initialize it uniquely, something like below but it doesn't work:

```
function InitializeShadowbox() {           
            Shadowbox[customLink].init({
                onOpen: shadowboxOpen,
                onFinish: shadowboxFinish,
                onClose: shadowboxClose,
                modal: true
            });
            // this will cause the shadowbox to setup itself again after a partial porstback.
            Shadowbox[customLink].setup();
        }
```

Update:
custom initialization added.

Thanks

Comment: Even from the very first page at their website, there are multiple shadowboxes. I don't understand why you think it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: if you look at their code, they only have one line of code where it says Shadowbox.init and they're simply using rel attribute. that's why. in my case, the way my shadowbox should be initialized for the first web user control is different from the second. so for example, for my first link when the shadowbox is opened, the close button should be shown whereas for the second one it shouldn't really and some other changes.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is built in.  Just give each link or group a unique name:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" rel="shadowbox[group1]">
   Google Logo
</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" rel="shadowbox[group1]">
   Google Logo
</a>

<a href="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_us_061509.png" rel="shadowbox[yahooLogo]">
   Yahoo Logo
</a>
```

Comment: thanks but I'd need to initialize it uniquely. e.g. shadowbox[login].init(...)

Comment: could you do that using e.g. Shadowbox[yahooLogo].open({
                content: "http://google.com",
                type: "iframe"
                , player: "html"                                    
            });

Comment: look at the shadowbox setup usage at the bottom of their guide: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html  You have to use a separate call to shadowbox.setup for each element.